# Having trouble with git commit

Tags: git, github

I am having trouble committing my work. Used vi to commit but the operation was aborted during the commit. I am getting the following error message. I tried git commit -m" but it seems to be stuck.

```
*Kanaks-MacBook-Pro:hrsf86-underbar kanaklata$ git commit 
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
Kanaks-MacBook-Pro:hrsf86-underbar kanaklata$ git commit -m"done with section 1*
>
```

Comment: `git commit -m "your message goes here, be sure to end with another quotation mark"` or fix `vi`.

Comment: You're missing `"`.

Comment: Or add `export EDITOR=nano` to your `.profile` to use that instead of `vi`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Alternatively, set `git config --global core.editor` to your editor of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing with additional “ mark. Can you retry by correcting it.